# Is it possible to get a number which consists only of digit 1?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

There is a number $n$, $n$ > $1$. The digits of the number $n$ are getting written in reversed order. After that the number is multiplied by $n$. Is it possible to get a number which would have only digit 1 in it?

Comment: Seems unlikely, though I don't think there's an easy proof.  It doesn't happen for $n \le 10^6$.

Comment: The last digit of the product of any two numbers is the last digit of the product of their individual last digits. Since our product has $1$ in its last digit, that means our numbers must also have last digits such that their product has $1$ as a last digit. This automatically narrows down our $n$, as $n$ now must be either  $1...1$ or $3...7$ or $7...3$. I can't program this properly enough though.

Comment: So the answer is **no** ? since the first digit in the second case can't be 1, and in the first case the digit of tens can't be 1.

Comment: The only problem is to prove it...

Comment: I think the question mark is misleading in my comment

Comment: @Student12 There is a number which only has one digit different: $1011 \times 1101 = 1113111$. This means that the best case has only none or one digit different.

Comment: Another one: $1010011\times 1100101=1111114111111$

Comment: this is not possible.

Comment: @mercio As Student12 said, prove it!

Comment: Seems to be an extremely difficult problem.